# Рекурсивное вычисление

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Есть код:

```js
function sum(...rest) {
    let res = 0;
    for (let num of rest) {
        res += num;
    }
    return res;
}

alert(sum(1, 5, 23, 2, 0, 9, 9)); // 49
```

Он складывает все аргументы, переданные функции. Вопрос: можно ли переписать эту функцию под рекурсию и если можно, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sum(...rest) {
  return (rest.length == 1) ? rest[0] : rest[0] + sum(...rest.slice(1));
}

console.log(sum(1, 5, 23, 2, 0, 9, 9)); // 49
```

Если остался один аргумент - вернуть его (`rest[0]`), иначе, сумму первого аргумента + результата вызова той же функции с оставшимися аргументами.

P.s. Если задачу получается достаточно легко решить обычным циклом - лучше выбрать цикл, чем рекурсию: Каждый вызов такой функции отправляется в стек вызовов, который не бесконечный. Скажем, если цикл требует больше 100 тыс. вызовов, большинство браузеров выдадут ошибку переполнения. А обычный цикл без проблем пройдет, и не заметит.

Тест бесконечной рекурсии:

```js
let i = 0;

setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000); // 84-й хром показывает 13974

(function moo() {
  i++;
  moo();
})();
```

Comment: _Каждый вызов такой функции отправляется в стек вызовов_ - если рекурсия хвостовая, то не каждый